# how to make Jquery menu sticky

Tags: jquery, menu, sticky

I found some menu code which is very simple and works nicely from just jquery without plugins. 
What I would like to do is to make it sticky so that when a new page is linked to, that page expands the menu (if necessary) down to the linked item and highlights that item as active if the current window.location matches the  tag href.
I've been wading through Dom console looking but I figure there must be a simpler jquery solution if I'm lucky.  any suggestions on how to achieve this much appreciated.
Thanks

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#menu ul').hide();

  /* Note the following three lines added as working solution to original question. */
  /* works for fully qualified url: i.e. http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.ext         */
  /* also note that addClass('current') requires .current class in your css          */

        var currentLink = $("a[href='" + location.href + "']");
        currentLink.parents("ul:hidden").slideDown("normal");
        currentLink.filter('a:first').addClass('current');

  /* end of solution fix                                                             */

        $('#menu li a').click(
         function() {
           var openMe = $(this).next();
           var mySiblings = $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul');
           if (openMe.is(':visible')) {
               openMe.slideUp('normal');  
           } else {
              mySiblings.slideUp('normal');  
              openMe.slideDown('normal');
           }
       });
    });
```

menu is as follows:

```
<ul id="menu">
 <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">2</a></li> 
 <li><a href="#">3</a>
     <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">3-1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">3-1-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3-1-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3-1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">3-2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">3-2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3-2-2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">5</a>
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#">5-1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">5-2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">5-3</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">6</a>
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#">6-1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">6-2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">6-3</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">7</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">8</a>
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#">8-1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">8-2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">8-3</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#" title="">9</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you can use `window.location.pathname` to identify the current page, then it's a matter of parsing the path to call `slideDown()` on the appropriate `ul`'s. Can you give us a hint about how your page URL's look so we can deliver a more specific answer?

Comment: links will either be absolute or just relative. I can create either from php. I can also create a class for current page so I guess its just the expansion to current item that I'm looking for but it would be more elegant to do it all in Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the bullet-proof way to find links with matching urls:

```
var currentLink = $("a").filter(function() {
    return this.href == location.href;
});
```

If you always use app relative URLs for your hrefs (eg `href="/abc/123.htm"`), you can use the attribute selector:

```
var appRelativeUrl = location.pathname + location.search + location.hash;
var currentLink = $("a[href='" + appRelativeUrl + "']");
```

If you always use absolute URLs for your hrefs (eg `href="http://mysite.com/abc/123.htm"`), you can also use the attribute selector:

```
var currentLink = $("a[href='" + location.href + "']");
```

But, if you use relative urls in your HTML, use the first technique using `.filter()`.

Then, to expand the menu, find all the hidden parent `<ul>` elements and slide them down.  After the parents are displayed, if you want to expand the link's submenu, issue a click on the link:

```
currentLink.parents("ul:hidden").slideDown("normal", function() {
    currentLink.click();
});
```

[Demo here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2dPYT/1/show/#3-1)
[Demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/2dPYT/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I think this puts me on the right track. The bit which says "find all the parent <UL> elements" is my next worry. What would be the construct to loop through each menu element so that I can find them? I'm new to Jquery but not to programing.

Comment: @RobC - In the code snippet at the end of my answer, notice the `currentLink.parents("ul:hidden")`. This returns all the ancestor elements of `currentLink` that are hidden `<ul>` elements.

Comment: @RobC - I've added working demo links to the end of my answer

Comment: You're a star. I had seen another script that uses hash for this purpose but it was massively mor complex than this simple and elegant solution.
Thanks again...

Comment: Problem!  Auto expand works nicely using location.href and not hash. But for some reason I can't fathom, no links from the menu work. It's as though they have all been disabled somehow.

Comment: @RobC - yes, `e.preventDefault()` is doing that.  Remove that line and the links will work.

Comment: I'm learning fast(ish). I modded the original code with my now working solution and another tweak for highlighting. Many thanks fo your help. See code in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically handled server-side by adding the appropriate class names to the current menu items when the page is served so they're visible.

Comment: I can make them either full url or relative but they all appear as being served from doamin root so currently either http://www.mydomain.com/mypage.htm or just mypage.htm